# python zeep error Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: zeep

buenas tardes estoy tratando de consumir un servicio soap con zeep de python y para esto ingrese a soapui para examinarlo y probar su funcionalidad la cual es correcta pero en el momento que realizo el client para su consumo me arroja este error
{
"error": "HTTPSConnectionPool(host='hera.xxx.xxx.co', port=4xxx7): Max retries exceeded with url: /IMC/TipoDocumento.svc (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)')))"
}

para esto el codigo va asi

from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport
from requests import Session
import urllib3

class WebService():

```
#soap_url = "https://hera.xxxx.xxx.co:xxxxx/IMC/TipoDocumento.svc?wsdl"

def consumir_servicio_cisa():
    try:
        #sesion =Session()
        #sesion.verify= './Escritorio/PruebaSOAP/consumoXML/certificados/hera_cisa_cert.pem'
        #tranport = Transport(session=sesion)
        #urllib3.disable_warnings()
        print("CONSUMIENDO SOAP")
        client = Client("https://hera.xxxx.xxx.co:4xxx7/IMC/TipoDocumento.svc?wsdl")
        
        print(f"CONEXIÓN EXITOSA SOAP:....{client}")
        
        response = client.service.ConsultarTipoDocumentoActivo(1)

        print("************************************************")
        print(response)
        print("************************************************")
        return response

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error al consumir el servicio SOAP: {str(e)}")
        raise

if __name__ == "__main__":
    consumir_servicio_cisa()
```

ya intente poner la verify=False con unos print de conexion y pasa hasta la conexion y trato de poner el transport con un archivo .pem que converti y lo guarde a la altura del script pero este me arroja que no encuentra el path hacia el .pem

Comment: Sorry, but ['basic' stackoverflow is English-only](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions). There are alternate -- though smaller -- stackoverflow versions for some other languages, including Spanish, linked there.